# Shrink image with text and put into other image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, resize, resolution

Okay I have this image with dimensions 2000x1333 px and resolution 240ppi.

[image]

And now I have this image which is where I am trying to put the image of the phone into, this second image is 1204x452 px and has resolution 300ppi. Now I want to shrink down the first image, the image with the phone, and keep the text looking sharp and then add it to this second image.

[image]

When I shrink the image the text gets all pixilated and looks bad I have been looking around for solutions to this for a while and just keep seeing the same thing which is to change bicubic to bicubic sharpen when changing the image size but this does not work nearly well enough. There must be a better way to keep text sharp when shrinking an image.

If anyone could help me with this that would be great.

Thanks for reading my question and thanks for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not, instead, enlargen the second image and put the first over that? The text would stay the same.

Or, shrink the top one a little and enlargen the bottom one a little.

Comment: Because I need the final size of the image to be 1204x452 for website

Comment: How 'bout this: Shrink the image, put it on top of the other one, then *delete the text*. Rewrite it with text tool, that may look a bit sharper.

Comment: Okay that's possible but how would I delete just the text

Comment: Color picker tool + paintbrush + a steady hand & patience. Keep another copy of the image open, though, to reference what the text says.

Comment: I tried that the text, can't be made small enough/ sharp enough

Comment: How bout this: Don't scale down the first image itself, but scale it down on the site. Then, on mouse rollover of the image, it expands to a readable size, and rolloff it contracts again.

Comment: I am making a static site

Comment: Not sure what to say, then. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

It will never be perfect because basically what you are doing is telling photoshop "give up on some pixels" but you let it decide which, and as a computer program it doesn't know if what it sees is text or just a random white pixel
2 solutions:
1.Open the screen in a different photoshop file, shrink it with the image size window using the best for reduction woption and bring it back to your original image:
[image]

2. Rewrite everything in your original app with a larger font size (what is that, 24 pixels? maybe bring it up to 28-30?)